# SQL Server: Replicate data from multiple tables into one

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

Is it possible to replicate data from multiple tables into one real time?

For example I have 3 tables:

- Table: **DriverLocation**
  Columns: DriverId, Latitude, Longtide, GpsLastUpdate, Speed, ...
- Table: **Driver**
  Columns: DriverId, FirstName, LastName, Address, IsActive, ...
- Table: **Job**
  Columns: JobId, DriverId, JobName, Pickup, Delivery, ...

I'd like to create a join query between these 3 tables and in real time publish that data into a table called `RealTimeDriverInfo`.

Example (pseudo code):

```
Driver(FirstName, LastName) 
JOIN DriverLocatoin(Latitude, Longitude) 
JOIN Job(JobName)
PUT RESULT IN REAL TIME INTO => RealTimeDriverInfo table
```

Is that possible?

EDIT: NOTE:

The reason I want the data to be in a table is because I would like to use this c# library to get real time notifications from a table, this libarary only works with tables and unfortunately you cannot join multiple tables only monitor one table, the library is SQLTableDependency

.NET Library to monitor chagnes in a SQL Table (it can only work with tables, NOT views and you can only monitor one table you cannot join multiple tables)
https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency

This is why I somehow need to join multiple tables into one table

Comment: You mean something like `Insert into RealTimeDriverInfo () select () from Driver JOIN DriverLocation on ... JOIN Job ..`? It depends though what you feel is realtime. You could fire a trigger that your database system automatically runs every time a row gets inserted, updated or deleted.

Comment: Why not create a Sql View instead?

Comment: @MarkKram The reason I want the data to be in a table is because I would like to use this c# library to get real time notifications from a table, this libarary only works with tables and unfortunately you cannot join multiple tables only monitor one table, the library is SQLTableDependency (https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency)

Answer (score 2):

First, a simple view may do what you want:

```
CREATE v_RealTimeDriverInfo 
    SELECT D.FirstName, D.LastName, DL.Latitude, DL.Longitude, J.JobName
    FROM Driver D JOIN
         DriverLocation DL
         ON D.DriverID = DL.DriverID JOIN
         Job J 
         ON J.DriverID = D.DriverID;
```

with indexes on the columns used for `JOIN`ing, this would usually be fast enough when querying.  This is the "standard" way to do what you want.

If you actually want a separate "virtual" table that is always up-to-date, then you want something akin to a *materialized view*, which SQL Server supports as [*indexed views*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15).  The idea is that the *index* is maintained "real-time" as the underlying data changes.

For your example, it would look like:

```
CREATE v_RealTimeDriverInfo 
    SELECT D.FirstName, D.LastName, DL.Latitude, DL.Longitude, J.JobName
    FROM Driver D JOIN
         DriverLocation DL
         ON D.DriverID = DL.DriverID JOIN
         Job J 
         ON J.DriverID = D.DriverID;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX v_RealTimeDriverInfo_pk ON (D.FirstName, D.LastName, DL.Latitude, DL.Longitude, J.JobName);
```

Comment: The reason I want the data to be in a table is because I would like to use this c# library to get real time notifications from a table, this libarary only works with tables and unfortunately you cannot join multiple tables only monitor one table, the library is SQLTableDependency (https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency)

Comment: @EricBergman . . . You are saying that it doesn't work with a view?  Does it work with an indexed view?

Comment: It doesn't work with any type of view it only works with tables.

Comment: @EricBergman - Can't you put a trigger on this view? Your trigger would update RealTimerDriverInfo table, and SQLTableDependency would monitor that 1 table.

Answer (score 1):

Is inserting into a different table necessary? A view would suffice in this instance. I am assuming that `JobId` is an integer that increments by one with each job. I use `CROSS APPLY` to pull in the most recent location and job. You'll also have to have some logic to determine whether or not the driver is on an active job.

```
select      a.FirstName     FirstName
            ,a.LastName     LastName
            ,b.Latitude     Latitude
            ,b.Longitude    Longitude
            ,c.JobName      JobName
from        Driver          a
cross apply (
                select      top 1
                            *
                from        DriverLocation  b
                where       b.DriverId = a.DriverId
                order by    b.GpsLastUpdate desc
            )               b
cross apply (
                select      top 1
                            c.*
                from        Job c
                where       c.DriverId = a.DriverId
                order by    c.JobId desc
            )               c
```

Comment: The reason I want the data to be in a table is because I would like to use this c# library to get real time notifications from a table, this libarary only works with tables and unfortunately you cannot join multiple tables only monitor one table, the library is SQLTableDependency (https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency)

Comment: In that I case, put an insert statement above tub select and it should work!

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, just a quick couple of JOINS.  But it seems that creating a view would probably serve you a little better.

```
INSERT INTO RealTimeDriverInfo (FirstName,LastName,Latitude,Longitude,JobName)
SELECT D.FirstName, D.LastName,DL.Latitude, DL.Longitude,J.JobName
FROM Driver D
INNER JOIN DriverLocation DL on D.DriverID = DL.DriverID
INNER JOIN Job J on J.DriverID = D.DriverID
```

Comment: . . I am confused by your answer.  You are recommending a view, but then don't show how to implement it.

Comment: I was answering the question he asked. I recommend he use a view, but given the limited info he provided I have no idea if in fact he really only wants to insert records. If he actually wants to use a view then your answer was perfect

Comment: @JM_ The reason I want the data to be in a table is because I would like to use this c# library to get real time notifications from a table, this libarary only works with tables and unfortunately you cannot join multiple tables only monitor one table, the library is SQLTableDependency (https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency)

Comment: @JM_ hope so too, just wondering if it's even possible to replicate multiple tables into one table in real time